# Where can I find the icon for a floating action button in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, icons, floating-action-button

I've tried googling pictures of one, but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to specify the color of the floating action button using hex in the layout file.
I want the color to make sense with the rest of the app.

Comment: The best places to search icons are: [materialdesignicons.com](https://materialdesignicons.com/) and [google design icons](https://design.google.com/icons/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of FAB by `app:backgroundTint` Attribute in FloatingActionButton XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_myicon"
app:backgroundTint="@color/mycolor"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:elevation="5dp">
```

Comment: Will that work with an image I get off google? There's no FAB icon in my drawables directory.

Comment: Yes it will work flawless but be sure to use a png image for icon

Answer (score 0):

you can set float action button color using colorAccent in syles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/drawer_toggle</item>
</style>
```

or if you don't want change colorAccent, you can use backgroundTint as deejay said.

Comment: Will that work if I download an image from google and put it in my drawables directory? My drawables directory didn't come with a floating action button icon